# How to display name of unknown incomming call number

Tags: android

In my app, I have a database of phone numbers. Each phone number has a name assigned to it.

When user receives incoming call from number that he has not saved in his contacts database I want to display name from my database instead of *unknown* label...

Is it possible? How can I achieve this?

Would it be possible to also display some additional labels? For example caller's company, gender, age... (all those information will be pulled from my database of course)

Comment: You can not manipulate the System caller app . But what you can do draw a view over it and show essential info about number just like TrueCaller app does .

Comment: @ADM. I don't need to draw another view over caller screen (but it may me alternative if I won't be able to find another solution...). I just need to set caller's name. When you for example call to some restaurant, you automatically see the name of that restaurant instead of just plain number. I need to do exactly the same with numbers in my database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I did some research and found this.

To change display name of incoming call number, I have to add a new contact. That may not be the best approach since it will create contact in user's contacts and will be preserved even after uninstalling the app...

Another option is to display overlay view on which can be shown name (and other labels) from my database. I think I will go with this solution...

Comment: That's the overhead I think . You are manipulating with users contact names . In that way you can misguide user as you just change his contact name or you made a duplicate of it.